# import function in octave

Tags: matlab, function, import, octave

I am running matlab code in octave. The import function is not implemented in core octave, I guess. Any idea how to use this matlabe function in octave?

Here is what I have:
octave-3.4.0:7> setup
Importing packages:
brml.*
warning: the `import' function is not yet implemented in Octave

Please read `http://www.octave.org/missing.html' to learn how you can
contribute missing functionality.

error: `import' undefined near line 8 column 5

Comment: Can you post your code where you use the `import` function?

Answer (score 6):

You can make your own custom import.m.  From http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/namespace-support-td1638758.html:

```
function import(varargin) 
 error(nargchk(1, inf, nargin, "struct")); 
 for i=1:nargin 
   [names, funcs] = import1(varargin{i}); 
   for j=1:length(names) 
     assignin("caller", names{j}, funcs{j}); 
   endfor 
 endfor 
endfunction 

function [names, funcs] = import1(pkgname) 
 pkgname_parts = strsplit(pkgname, "."); 
 if length(pkgname_parts) > 2 
   error("invalid package name: %s", pkgname); 
 endif 
 pkgpath = locatepkg(pkgname_parts{1}); 
 unwind_protect 
   cwd = pwd; 
   cd(pkgpath); 
   names = what(pwd); 
   names = {names.m{:}, names.mex{:}, names.oct{:}}; 
   names = cellfun(@stripExtension, names, "UniformOutput", false); 
   if length(pkgname_parts) == 2 
     if any(strcmp(pkgname_parts{2}, names)) 
       names = {pkgname_parts{2}}; 
     else 
       error("function `%s' not found in package `%s'", ... 
         pkgname_parts{2}, pkgname_parts{1}); 
     endif 
   endif 
   funcs = cellfun(@str2func, names, "UniformOutput", false); 
 unwind_protect_cleanup 
   cd(cwd); 
 end_unwind_protect 
endfunction 

function pkgpath = locatepkg(pkgname) 
 pathdirs = strsplit(path, pathsep); 
 for iPath=1:length(pathdirs) 
   pkgpath = [pathdirs{iPath} filesep "+" pkgname]; 
   if exist(pkgpath, "dir") 
     return; 
   endif 
 endfor 
 error("package `%s' cannot be located in the path", pkgname); 
endfunction 

function fileName = stripExtension(fileName) 
 dotIndices = strfind(fileName, "."); 
 fileName = fileName(1:(dotIndices(end)-1)); 
endfunction
```

Comment: Is it also possible to have a Import function from Scilab / ScosLab? I'm trying to solve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55112860/4999991).