# using an if statement to have an intracompatible code between Octave and MATLAB

Tags: matlab, octave, portability, mixed-programming

On par with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55112860/4999991), I want to have some pieces of code which only run depending if the interpreter is either MATLAB or Octave. For example

```matlab
if Octave
    % Octave specific code
elseif MATLAB
    % MATLAB specific code
else
    % other stuff
end
```

both Octave and MATLAB have `version` or `version()` command which return

> ans = 5.1.0

and

> ans =
>
> '9.5.0.1049112 (R2018b) Update 3'

respectively. I could use regex to define a function to distinguish them but I was wondering if there is a more canonical and faster solution?

Comment: @rinkert possibly. will check. thanks.

Comment: @rinkert it seems to be a very similar question. however the answers on that page are not that good either. mostly work around. :(

Comment: I disagree, the second answer (referring to [this](https://wiki.octave.org/Compatibility) wiki) is from the Octave wiki, and thus I see it as the recommended approach.

Comment: There are many ways, but the first two answers in the linked question (which are identical) are the recommended way of doing it. Other methods might break in future releases, this one is future proof.